Change windows accent colors for all users
I have been working on this for a while now and cant seem to get it working.  I am running a powershell script on my server that loads ntuser.dat and updates the accent color.  This way any new user that logs on should get these settings.  I verify eveything is there but windows is ignoring they settings and still using the stock blue color.
My goal is to brand my server with the powershell script for all users with our company color scheme.
Here is the script i am using for reference
New-Item -Path "C:\Windows\Web\Wallpaper\Staging" -ItemType "Directory" -Force -Confirm:$false | out-null
copy-item -path \\cdshare\technet\citrix\BGInfo\BGinfo\UH_Login.jpg -destination C:\Windows\Web\Wallpaper\Staging\background.jpg -force -confirm:$false
copy-item -path \\cdshare\technet\citrix\BGInfo\BGinfo\UH_Citrix_wallpaper.jpg -destination C:\Windows\Web\Wallpaper\Staging\UH_Citrix_wallpaper.jpg -force -confirm:$false
REG LOAD HKEY_USERS\ZZZ C:\USERS\DEFAULT\NTUSER.DAT
REG ADD "HKEY_USERS\ZZZ\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Accent" /f /v "AccentColorMenu" /t REG_DWORD /d 0xff59544a
REG ADD "HKEY_USERS\ZZZ\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Accent" /f /v "StartColorMenu" /t REG_DWORD /d 0xff59544a
REG ADD "HKEY_USERS\ZZZ\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\DWM" /f /v "AccentColor" /t REG_DWORD /d 0xff59544a
REG ADD "HKEY_USERS\ZZZ\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\DWM" /f /v "ColorPrevalence" /t REG_DWORD /d 0x00000001
REG UNLOAD HKEY_USERS\ZZZ
REG ADD "HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Accent" /f /v "AccentColorMenu" /t REG_DWORD /d 0xff59544a
REG ADD "HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Accent" /f /v "StartColorMenu" /t REG_DWORD /d 0xff59544a
REG ADD "HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\DWM" /f /v "AccentColor" /t REG_DWORD /d 0xff59544a
REG ADD "HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\DWM" /f /v "ColorPrevalence" /t REG_DWORD /d 0x00000001
REG ADD "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Accent" /f /v "DefaultStartColor" /t REG_DWORD /d 0xff59544a
takeown /f C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\SystemData /a /r /d y
takeown /f C:\Windows\Web\Screen\img100.jpg /a
icacls C:\Windows\Web\Screen\img100.jpg /grant Administrators:F
$lockscreen = "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\SystemData\S-1-5-18\ReadOnly\LockScreen_Z"
$tempfolder = "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\SystemData\S-1-5-18\ReadOnly\LockScreen_Temp"
$img100 = Get-ChildItem C:\Windows\WinSxS -Recurse -Include img100.jpg
write-host $img100
takeown /f $img100 /a
icacls $img100 /grant Administrators:F /q
$img0 = Get-ChildItem C:\Windows\WinSxS -Recurse -Include img0.jpg
write-host $img0
takeown /f $img0 /a
icacls $img0 /grant Administrators:F /q
copy-item -path C:\Windows\Web\Wallpaper\Staging\background.jpg -destination $img100 -force -confirm:$false | out-null
copy-item -path C:\Windows\Web\Wallpaper\Staging\UH_Citrix_wallpaper.jpg -destination C:\Windows\Web\Wallpaper\Windows\img0.jpg -force -confirm:$false | out-null
copy-item -path C:\Windows\Web\Wallpaper\Staging\background.jpg -destination C:\Windows\Web\Screen\img100.jpg -force -confirm:$false | out-null
New-Item -Path $tempfolder -ItemType "Directory" | out-null
Robocopy $tempfolder $lockscreen /zb /mir /njh /njs
Remove-Item -Path $tempfolder -force -confirm:$false | out-null


From edited hive, i'm using different paths(my settings apply to all new users) for example;(reg add "HKEY_USERS\NamedDefUser\Control Panel\Desktop" /v AutoColorization/t  REG_DWORD /d 1 /f).
Your "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer" edits are for folder appearance, when you open them, for example;(reg add "HKEY_USERS\NamedDefUser\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" /v Hidden /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f) to hide hidden files and folders.

What should i use for the default user then?  Above you have NamedDefUser.  I assume that is a place holder.  What should i use here?

When you use in RegEdit a "Load Hive" function, you can name that as you want. I never use anything (in naming) that Windows might use IE ".Default", instead i load that default hive under "NamedDefUser" or "myUserToEdit", it does not matter, when you "unload hive", that particular data will not be written.

There's a typo on lines 7-8: Windows\DVM should be Windows\DWM

I noticed that updating the accent color from the settings app changes a couple other values, which may or may not be necessary:
\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Accent\AccentPalette
\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\DWM\ColorizationColor
\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\DWM\ColorizationAfterglow


Also, The .Default user is not the default user. It's for the NT Authority\SYSTEM account, and you generally shouldn't add personalization changes there.

Your last part of comment is wrong. To make it more clear .Default is a "layout" used for any new created user, this is first hive that applies, then rest comes on it(in short).

@Danijel yes, windows will use the values from .Default if there are no matching registry values in the C:\USERS\DEFAULT\NTUSER.DAT hive or the user's own profile. .Default is still the wrong place to make these kind of changes. It's effectively redundant, gets overwritten by anything else, and is also used for repairing profiles if I remember correctly, so making manual changes to it can get you stuck hard if you accidentally add a bad value.

Can't confirm at all that it get "overwritten", quite the opposite, as long as there are no same values dictated by gpo, the values from .Default hive will be applied to all new users, values that you add, and dont exist, wont be overwritten with anything else that is "default" by windows. And yes, i 100% agree with last statement, must be sure what are you changing and have it confirmed.
